# Trying append image in the div whenever ajax calls in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hey guys trying to send image in the .append so whenever my ajax loads the image is shown. but when i use pass the value like this

```
$("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; ">' + '<a>' + '<?php echo img($user_image); ?>' + '</a>' + '<a>' + ' <?php echo $uname; ?>' + '</a>' + '<div>' + image_status + '</div>' + '</div>');
```

Here `image_status` is my image which shows object element error in firebug and when it sends it like this it shows error that object HTML element:

```
$("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; ">' + '<a>' + '<?php echo img($user_image); ?>' + '</a>' + '<a>' + ' <?php echo $uname; ?>' + '</a>' + '<div>' + '<img src="' + <?php base_url(uploads/) ?>status_image + '">' + '</div>' + '</div>');
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');

    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
        data: "id=" + lastID,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(html) {
          $('.load-more').show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
          var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

          $PostId = json[4]['id'];
          for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var post_status = json[i]['status'];
            $status_image = json[i]['status_image'];
            var multimage = json[i]['multimage'];

            alert($status_image);

            $("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; ">' + '<a>' + '<?php echo img($user_image); ?>' + '</a>' + '<a>' + ' <?php echo $uname; ?>' + '</a>' + '<div>' + post_status + '</div>' + '</div>');

            $("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; ">' + '<a>' + '<?php echo img($user_image); ?>' + '</a>' + '<a>' + ' <?php echo $uname; ?>' + '</a>' + '<div>' + '<img src="' + <?php base_url('uploads/'); ?>
              status_image + '">' + '</div>' + '</div>');
          }
          $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $PostId);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What can I do to append the image every time AJAX loads can anybody give me any suggestions?

Comment: Just FYI, there is *a lot* of unnecessary string concatenation in your first two code examples.

Comment: that is what i need to append with my data in correct order @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You can simplify it to a single string: `$("#status_data").append('<div style="margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px;"><a><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a><?php echo $uname; ?></a><div>' + image_status + '</div></div>');`
`

Comment: ok got that @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: but what about echo the image_status? @RoryMcCrossan